# VBA - IIF Statement with CDate(variant)

Tags: excel, vba

I just started learning VBA three weeks ago, so feel free to critique my code.

I would like to use `IIF` statement to do what is inside the If statement:

```
Dim rng_ModPlanStart as range
Dim QueryDate as Variant

Set rng_ModPlanStart = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AH2:AH" & LastCell)
rng_ModPlanStart(1).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Module Planned Start"

    For Each cl In rng_ModPlanStart
        QueryDate = Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & cl.Row), Sheets("Chamber Schedule").Range("B:U"), 20, False)
        If Not ((IsError(QueryDate))) Then
        cl.Value = DateDiff("d", CDate(QueryDate), Date)
        End If
    Next cl
```

But I get an error when trying to use the IIF like

```
IIF(IsError(QueryDate), "", DateDiff("d", CDate(QueryDate), Date))
```

because VBA thinks QueryDate is not a date... which it should be by the CDate function right? What am I missing?

Comment: Variant can be everything. Did you ever check it's content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use `IIf` for this (or for almost anything IMHO).  The problem is that `IIf` isn't a "statement" - it's a *function*.  That means that all of the parameters are evaluated *before* they are passed to the `IIf` function.  So, it evaluates (in order):

```
IsError(QueryDate)
""
DateDiff("d", CDate(QueryDate), Date)   'This is still evaluated if IsError returns True.
```

That means you'll get a runtime error, because you'll be calling `DateDiff` regardless of whether `QueryDate` is an error.

`IIf` isn't like a ternary expression in other languages, so you can't use it for guard clauses.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Like VBA's logical operators, `IIF` does not have the [short-circuiting semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (unlike C and family). Therefore the error case is not handled the same way as with an `If Then else` statement.

```
IIF(IsError(QueryDate), "", DateDiff("d", CDate(QueryDate), Date))
```

Here even if `IsError` returns true, the second case which includes `CDate(QueryDate)` **will be evaluated**, resulting in a run-time error.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I thought it seemed efficient but I was wrong!